# StarCraft 1 - grid layout

Tags: starcraft, keyboard

I'm playing StarCraft 2 with grid layout. Is it possible to use this layout in StarCraft 1? I would like to go through the single player, but the hotkeys are just killing me.

Comment: Why would you possibly want to go back to StarCraft 1 after playing 2? Honestly! [/troll] But seriously, I'm so glad to see more and more people with this problem. Grid layout is seriously nothing short of amazing, best new feature of Starcraft 2, hands down. (If you discount all the amazing graphics, the new units, the maps, the storyline, the new tree, the dialog, the Galaxy Editor, ... what else did I miss?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the original StarCraft didn't allow the changing of the keybindings.

Comment: There's no official way, but it's perfectly possible (through modifying game files by specialized utilities).

Answer (score 2):

http://www.gosugamers.net/starcraft/features.php?i=a&id=1&start=50

http://www.icyhell.net/2008/05/18/keycraft-v100/

These may help, but they seem a bit technical, so be prepared!